# How can I use Redirected url from Apache in my routing.yml config in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

**apache rewrite rule**

```
RewriteRule ^/testapi/v1/user/login /symfonyProject/app.php/api/v1/login [QSA,PT,L]
```

**routing.yml config** in symfonyProject

Following config is giving exception:

exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException'

```
login_app:
    pattern:  /api/v1/login
    defaults: { _controller: APIBundle:UserTask:login}
```

But this is **working fine** :

```
login_app:
    pattern:  /testapi/v1/user/login
    defaults: { _controller: APIBundle:UserTask:login}
```

Hitting from URL : http://sourcecode.com/testapi/v1/user/login

I think, this is because it is taking **Request_uri** into account while finding the route

How can I make use of **1st method** in my symfony2 app?

Comment: What url are you testing?

Comment: `Following config is giving error` Can u add the error to your question?

Comment: @smarber- I've added the exception. please check!!